# Optimizing code - Comparison between Mathcad and Python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

`SL_Only`, pandas dataframe, contains signals from three transmitters at 13K locations (records)
`SL_Only` shape is 13722x3 all dtypes are `numeric`.
`TxID_L`, pandas dataframe, shape is 3x10 contains the 10 parameters for the three transmitters in `SL_Only`.

`F_BW` = [700, 2100, step_size=200]
`CF` = [20, 120,  step_size= 5]
`TxID` = str , can be anything
SC_SL = best of `TxID`

Barring `TxIDs`, all the values are `numeric`

```
SC_SL = '<Best column_name from SL_Only>'
row_arr = []

for _, r in tqdm(SL_Only.iterrows()):
    max_rsrp = SL_Only[SC_SL][_]
    max_txid = (r == max_rsrp).T.idxmax()
    paramax_cf = TxID_L[TxID_L['TxID'] == max_txid]['CF'].values
    paramax_bw = TxID_L[TxID_L['TxID'] == max_txid]['F_BW'].values
    col_arr = []
    for c in SL_Only.columns.values:
        rsrp = r[c]
        txid = (r == rsrp).T.idxmax()
        param_cf = TxID_L[TxID_L['TxID'] == txid]['CF'].values
        param_bw = TxID_L[TxID_L['TxID'] == txid]['F_BW'].values
        calc = rsrp + 10*np.log10(abs((paramax_cf+0.5*paramax_bw - param_cf+0.5*param_bw)/paramax_bw))
        col_arr.append(calc[0])
    row_arr.append(col_arr)
```

`row_arr` takes 1.5 minutes to process, whereas in `Mathcad` takes fractions of a second (I haven't used it, but my Manager told it works so.).

Can you find mistake in the code so it takes less time to process

Comment: What is the type and range of the _signals_?

Comment: `F_BW` = [700, 2100, step_size=200]
`CF` = [20, 120,  step_size= 5]
`TxID` = str , can be anything
SC_SL = best of `TxID`

Barring `TxIDs`, all the values are `numeric`

Comment: For benchmarking type programs like this you will get much better response from the community if you include code which generates realistic versions of these inputs, so that we can actually run the code instead of just looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written some code which generates fake inputs which at least allow me to run the code you posted without modification:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

TxIDs = ['sensor1', 'sensor2', 'sensor3']
params = ['CF', 'F_BW']

nsensors = len(TxIDs)
nmeasurements = 13722

SL_Only = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(nmeasurements, nsensors)), columns=TxIDs)
TxID_L = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(nsensors, len(params))), columns=params)
TxID_L['TxID'] = TxIDs
SC_SL = 'sensor1'
```

After these definitions, running your code (which takes about 45 seconds on my machine) produces a list of lists `row_arr`. To compare results, I define

```
old_result = pd.DataFrame(row_arr, columns=SL_Only.columns.values)
```

The following code duplicates your results and takes about 0.2 seconds:

```
TxID_L.set_index('TxID', inplace=True)

paramax_cf = TxID_L.loc[SC_SL, 'CF']
paramax_bw = TxID_L.loc[SC_SL, 'F_BW']
param_bw = TxID_L.loc[:, 'F_BW']
param_cf = TxID_L.loc[:, 'CF']

new_result = SL_Only + 10*np.log10(abs((paramax_cf+0.5*paramax_bw - param_cf+0.5*param_bw)/paramax_bw))
```

To confirm this, I do

```
(new_result - old_result).abs().values.max()
```

which has returned zero for every run I've made of this code.

Key insights are to do as much as you can only once instead of looping and to use the vectorised operations Pandas provides.

Comment: is it possible to reduce that ~45 secs (my machine takes more than 1.25 minutes) we are running?

Comment: @SantoshKV I'm not sure I follow. The replacement code I show here does the same thing as your code is less than a second - that's the improvement.